# Secure credentials in Angular 4 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, security, credentials

From my angular 4 `typescript` code, i am using **HttpClient** to call RESTful services. To call REST services, i am passing plain basic auth credentials in HTTP header like below:

`let headers: Headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic username:password');
this.httpClient.post(url, body, { headers: headers })`

I need to secure username and password in the typescript code since typescript will convert to java script (after build) which i guess hacker can dig into the bundled js files and take this plain credentials and use it for attacks.

Could someone help me giving ideas to secure my plain credentials in typescript code?

Comment: There is no solution to this. The design is flawed if it requires hard coded credentials..

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Angular is used to build single page application using java script.That's why there is no way to secure your token or every thing. You can secure your token or everything from back-end (using api's) by using package like **JWT**.